# Heroku Log "npm err"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I deployed an app to heroku, which worked, but when I go to the link, I get an application error. When I go to the heroku logs in my console, this is what I see:

```
2015-05-11T21:35:28.450778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2015-05-11T21:35:28.451031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the showtrackr@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2015-05-11T21:35:28.458702+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-05-11T21:35:28.451298+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the showtrackr package,
2015-05-11T21:35:28.470607+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-05-11T21:35:28.448240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
2015-05-11T21:35:28.471022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2015-05-11T21:35:28.458465+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-05-11T21:35:28.458841+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-05-11T21:35:28.471756+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-05-11T21:35:28.459009+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-05-11T21:35:28.459145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls showtrackr
2015-05-11T21:35:28.459299+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-05-11T21:35:29.488054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-11T21:35:29.489121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-11T21:35:29.467921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-11T21:35:33.804208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-05-11T21:35:35.767544+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-05-11T21:35:35.767452+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-05-11T21:35:37.227415+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
```

If anyone can help with this, that would be awesome.

Comment: What does your `./bin/www` file look like?  There's something going wrong in there.

Comment: It's probably the one generated by `generator-express` from this guide http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/

Comment: I noticed this step from that broken guide: "Remove  views,  routes and  bin directories because you will not be needing them anymore" -- You didn't happen to follow that advice did you? Because if your package.json is looking for bin/www and it doesn't exist then there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but I ran

`npm install`

and repushed to heroku and everything worked.

Comment: bummer. i'm in the same boat now.